# Windows 8.1 update stuck on update 16 of 23. Toshiba Z830 doesn't have a hard reset button. What do I do?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update, hibernate, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba Z830 running Windows 8.1 and I tried updating it today by rebooting. It got stuck on update 16 of 23. I couldn't reboot because my off button is assigned to sleep. Holding it in for 10 secs plus doesn't help either, because it instantly goes to sleep upon key down (not key up). The only way I got my computer to reboot was to drain the battery and then plug in the power.

That didn't solve my issue either, as I can't get into the Windows recovery menu. I've tried hammering <kbd>F12</kbd> for BIOS menu, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for Windows menu. Neither helps, as it resumes Windows anyway. It seems as it is recovering from hibernate instead of a clean boot.

What can I do to get out of this stalemate?

Comment: That [particular laptop](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/portege/z830) is an ultrabook - no modular battery, so removing the battery is likely quite a chore.  From the sounds of it, it probably got to a low battery level and hibernated, so now when booting, it's not a cold boot, but a semi-warm boot that's trying to wake from hibernation, which is why you can't get to the boot menu.

Comment: The BIOS key for Toshiba could also be F2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see this type of issue again, performing a quick Tap + Tap-Hold on the power button should do the trick.  (Two taps in quick succession, where you hold the power button in on the second tap.)

I ran into a similar issue with my Z830 today, and this is what I was able to do to force it to shut down.  After further testing, I did notice that I sometimes needed to do this process twice, since the first time it would sometimes just put the laptop to Sleep (or wake it back up).

Answer (score 0):

To reset a laptop easily when in that situation, just take the battery off, no need to drain it which takes a long time and isn't that good for the battery.

As for the startup, if the laptop is too fast to allow you to get into one of the startup modes, I would probably resort to removing the hard drive temporarily so it can't boot. Then go into the BIOS and change the settings to give you startup options. Before you do that though, try some other keys. Escape sometimes works as does Delete, depends on the BIOS.

You should be able to get at least to the Windows recovery options menu & choose to start in safe mode.

Another option might be to use another PC to mount the drive and remove the hibernation file.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the battery is internal and not easily disconnected. But that was what I ended up doing anyway. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disconnecting the battery after opening the casing (13 screws). Way more complicated and risky than I appreciated, but after that Windows was able to self-recover.